# I need to build a interface in wpf, something similar to TFS query interface

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to build a interface in wpf, something similar to TFS query interface where I can do grouping and ungrouping rows any suggestions?

Comment: My first suggestion is, please try to rewrite this question to be more specific. For which part of building the interface do you require suggestions? Grouping/Ungrouping items? What sort of items? How must they be displayed?

Comment: Grouping and up grouping of rows and to add the brackets as in TFS querry interface.

Comment: This site is intended to generally give **specific** answers to **specific** questions.  If you're looking for a very general answer, this isn't really the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far your answer is very generic, but simply for grouping of rows in a view, you might want to start by looking at `ListView` combined with `CollectionViewSource`.  `CollectionViewSource` will allow you to set grouping on a property, and `ListView` will let you visualize that in WPF.

Comment: Thanks Jhon, I know my question was very generic but the answer you gave is really going to help me. Thanks again for you suggestion.